# Firebase message works when app in background and foreground. However when app terminated no notifications

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to flutter and firebase and have followed the documentation best I could.
FCM seems to work when the app is in the foreground and background. However, when the app is terminated I do not get any notifications. I have looked at the app permissions etc and all seem to be fine.

pubspec.yml
firebase_messaging: ^11.2.5

```
class PushNotificationService {
  final FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  Future initialize() async {

    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );


    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print('User granted permission');
    } else if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
      print('User granted provisional permission');
    } else {
      print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
    }

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
      print('Message data: ${message.data}');

      if (message.notification != null) {
        print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}




Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "",
      authDomain: '',
      databaseURL: "",
      projectId: "",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: '',
      appId: "",
      measurementId: '',
    ),
  );

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title
     description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
     importance: Importance.high,
  );

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

home.dart

```
class _HomeTabState extends State<HomeTab> {


  void pushnotifications()async{
    PushNotificationService pushNotificationService=PushNotificationService();
    pushNotificationService.initialize();
    pushNotificationService.getToken();
  }




  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    pushnotifications();

  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
    ));
  }
```

Androidmanifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


   <application
        android:label=""
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
             <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value=""/>

       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
           android:value="high_importance_channel" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Json Payload

```
{
    "to": "",
    "notification": {
        "body": "This is the body",
        "title": "This is the title"
    },
    "priority": "high"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably also add a listener for `getInitialMessage()` on firebase message instance. This will fetch the notifications when app is terminated.

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage()
        .then((RemoteMessage? message) {
      if (message != null) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(
          context,
          '/message',
          arguments: MessageArguments(message, true),
        );
      }
    });
```

Refer: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/example

Comment: Hi there. I just tried that and there is no difference. When the app is on messages come through. When the app is minimized (pressed home button) messages still come through. When the app is closed no messages come through. However when i open the app again and wait 10 mins all the missed messages come in

Comment: I observed that when app is in background or terminated, it invoked _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler and the printed message display on console, however, the app remain in background or terminated, Please how do i bring the app to foreground when _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler is called?